# Magento 2 get product id from admin product edit page but i am not able to get

Tags: magento2

I am want to get product SKU in my constructor through my block even I try product repository  still null value is coming

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Valuecoders\RpmInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Rmpinventorysynchistory\CollectionFactory;
use Valuecoders\RpmInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Rmpinventorysynchistory\Collection;
use Valuecoders\RpmInventory\Model\Rmpinventorysynchistory;
use Valuecoders\RpmInventory\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Demo;


class CustomDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @var RequestInterface
 */
protected $request;
protected $block;
private $productRepository; 



/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request1,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,


    Demo $currentProduct,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->block = $currentProduct;
    $this->request = $request1;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}

 */

public function getData()
{
      var_dump($this->productRepository->getSku();
//$this->block->getSku();
}
```

But still, always show Null Value please help me to shootout this problem

Comment: where you have loaded the repository?

Comment: @RakeshVarma ui component

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that you have got the ui Component successfully declared and loaded it looks like your interpretation of how to use productRepository is incorrect.

```
$productId = $this->request->getParam('id');
```

Request should be able to retreive the URL id param (edit page will be something like admin/catalog/product/edit/id/

From that you should be able to use the Product Repository to load the product

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
return $product->getSku();
```

Comment: yes you correct my UI component is loaded correctly I need to filter my data on the bases of SKU I try your code still same issue i want to print sku through block or any method but i am not able to load